# Replace nan cells with lists in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

| index | title | Open | Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009-02-13 | [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... | 7933.000000 | 7850.410156 |
| 2009-02-14 | [613, 6294, 19, 251, 1463, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0... | NaN | NaN |
| 2009-02-17 | NaN | 7845.629883 | 7552.600098 |
| 2009-02-18 | NaN | 7546.350098 | 7555.629883 |
| 2009-02-19 | NaN | 7555.229980 | 7465.950195 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2020-06-07 | [29, 68, 245, 3496, 62, 32, 20, 9, 11, 141, 32... | NaN | NaN |
| 2020-06-08 | [898, 30, 22, 1739, 47, 733, 8, 1182, 0, 0, 0,... | 27232.929688 | 27572.439453 |

where the title column is an indexed tokenization of news titles. I cannot discard the NaN rows because they will be relevant for later processing. Instead, I want to make replace NaN values with lists of zeros of the same size of the not-NaN cells.

I created a zeros list with:

```
max_wid = dataframe["title"].map(lambda x: len(x)).max()
zeros = np.zeros(max_wid, dtype=int).tolist()
```

I managed to assign the list in the first row with `.at` but it's not feasible to replace all rows manually, although it's the only tip I found online.

I've tried using `.loc[dataframe.title.isnull(), "title"] = zeros` but it will return a  `ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value`.

I thought of using itertuples but it doesn't allow to set attributes and iterrows is discouraged.

Any help is extremely appreciated.

### EDIT

I found an inefficient and inelegant solution by doing this:

```
zeros = np.zeros(max_wid, dtype=int).tolist()
dataframe["isna"] = dataframe.title.isna()
check = dataframe["isna"].values
title = dataframe["title"].values
test = np.empty((dataframe.shape[0]), dtype=object)

for i,v in enumerate(test):
  if check[i] == True:
    test[i] = zeros
  else:
    test[i] = title[i]

dataframe["title"] = test.tolist()
dataframe.drop("isna", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

If anyone can come up with a more optimized solution, I'll still appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Take a look to [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method

Comment: Ciao Nicolò and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: @PauloMarques I already tried with that too but unfortunately the value for fillna can't be a list.

Comment: How could you apply `max_wid = dataframe["title"].map(lambda x: len(x)).max()` without getting `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution: Just use `fillna` on `string(list)` instead of raw `list` and parse `str(list)` into `list` back using apt to make that in `df['title']` all rows have the same type in each row. Solution is completely vectorized, so it has to be fast enough

You are right, `fillna` does not work on `list` type but you always can trick it :).

```py
import pandas as pd
import ast

data = {"index":{"0": "2009-02-13",
                 "1": "2009-02-14",
                 "2": "2009-02-15"
                },
        "title": {"0": [1, 0, 0],
                 "1": [613, 6294, 19]},
        "Open": {"0": 7893,
                 "2": 7845},
        "Close": {"0": 7850,
                  "2": 7855,}
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mask_isna = df['title'].isna()

max_wid = df.loc[~mask_isna, "title"].str.len().max()
zeros = np.zeros(max_wid, dtype=int).tolist()

df['title'] = df['title'].fillna(str(zeros))
df.loc[mask_isna, 'title'] = df.loc[mask_isna, 'title'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df 
index title Open Close
0   2009-02-13  [1, 0, 0]   7893.0  7850.0
1   2009-02-14  [613, 6294, 19]     NaN     NaN
2   2009-02-15  [0, 0, 0]   7845.0  7855.0
```

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
mask = df.title.notna()

max_wid = df.loc[mask, "title"].str.len().max()
zeros = np.zeros(max_wid, dtype=int).tolist()

df.loc[~mask, "title"] = [zeros]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        index            title
0  2009-02-13        [1, 0, 0]
1  2009-02-14  [613, 6294, 19]
2  2009-02-15        [0, 0, 0]
3  2009-02-16        [0, 0, 0]
```

---

`df` used:

```
        index            title
0  2009-02-13        [1, 0, 0]
1  2009-02-14  [613, 6294, 19]
2  2009-02-15              NaN
3  2009-02-16              NaN
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but I get the same ValueError as in the question when i call `df.loc[~mask, "title"] = [zeros]`...

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried using `.loc[dataframe.title.isnull(), "title"] = zeros` but it will return a  `ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value`.

You can complete this approach with the aid of a helper Series:

```
dataframe.loc[dataframe.title.isnull(), "title"] = pd.Series((zeros,)*dataframe.shape[0], dataframe.index)
```